# vague phrasing: characteristically

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning, phrase-meaning

In Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary, the adverb **characteristically** means "​in a way that is very **typical** of something or of somebody's character."
In the following extract from *Frankenstein*, who or what is the phrasing "advancement in his profession" characteristic (or typical) of?

> . . . he is madly desirous of glory, or rather, to word my phrase more **characteristically**, of advancement in his profession.

Comment: *He is desirous of advancement in his profession* is perhaps more characteristically imaginable  than *He is desirous of some unknown glory*?

Comment: It's not quite clear what this is asking. If it's asking what **characteristically** is *referring* to, it's **glory**. In short **glory** → **advancement in his profession**.